# display php file content in the javascript of another php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

So basically i want to `html()` a php file but i seem to fail, maybe it isn't possible but i want to make sure.

This is an example code (not the real one):
`page.php`:

```
<? //some code generating html ?>

<div class='content'></div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('.content').html("<? include('php/content.php'); ?>");
</script>
```

`php/content.php`:

```
<div class='realContent'>Awesome Stuff Here</div>
```

Note: I know there is `.load()`, `$.post` and many others. I just want to know if this practic is possible, `.html()`-ing a php file's contents.
Thank you in advance, awesome community!

Comment: its not directly possible. u can do it through AJAX.

Comment: @harry Yeah i know about the ajax method, but there is no way of getting the contents inside that html function? i was thinking logically and because php "runs before javascript" i was thinking it must be possible.

Comment: what exactly does not work?

Comment: you code should actually work, probably quotes inside the php file mess with the ones in js tho

Comment: @KirillPisarev do not get any content inside <div class='content'></div>

Comment: @DavidFregoli Hm, that seems logical, let me check

Comment: did you looked in source code? show us what appers in place of `<? include('php/content.php'); ?>`

Comment: just to be clear, that won't echo the php source but whatever the php echoes

Comment: @DavidFregoli The quotes aren't messing with the javascript ones, the real code is exactly as showed in the example but with much more javascript. Also if i try with .html("<?='hi!'?>"); it is working

Comment: what is getting printed in the source code inside html() now?

Comment: @DavidFregoli a white space.

Comment: then the included php doesn't have any echo statement

Answer (score -1):

d3nm4k.
The code in my example does what you want.
Maybe you got the problem with the short opening tags that is < ? ? >. 
The file I'm trying to load in my example is located in app/View/Tests/def.php and works just fine.

Hope it helped you!

```
<div class='content'></div>

<?php 
$fileLocation = APP . 'View/Tests/def.php';

// Ensure the file exists
echo "FILE EXISTS: <b>" . (file_exists($fileLocation) ? "TRUE" : "FALSE") . "</b><br /><br />";
?>

<?php 
// Alternatively, you can try this one
//include $fileLocation; 
?>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$('.content').html("<?php include($fileLocation); ?>");
</script>
```

Comment: I dont understand why mine isn't working, you sure you have html inside the def.php file? The thing is, if i replace <?php include($file) ?> with the actual content of the file, it works.

Comment: Yes. I'm pretty sure it's in the def.php file. Have you tried checking your error console log in your browser (F12) ? Maybe you don't have jQuery?
And does the alternative solution I've included work for you?
Also try to analyze the problem looking in the sourcecode (Ctrl+U) of the website. If an error occurs in the javascript, you won't see it in the actual website's output visible.

Comment: So the thing is, in my example code, if i replace the php/contents.php contents with echo("Hi"); everything works. But if i have exactly what i have in the example code, it only displays a white space. (no errors in console not errors anywhere, just a white space)

Comment: Ah, I think I know what might the problem. You see, if the simple "Hi" works for you, then it may be problem with proper string. Keep in mind, when you include a file the line:
html("<?php include($fileLocation); ?>") 
may suddenly become : 
html("abcadditional_apostrophes""") // wrong syntax

You would need to remove these apostrophes. Try tracking down all these extra characters and leave just the text. Take a look at function: 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

Answer (score -2):

You can do it, the code you gave i tried it just by adding ?php

```
<div class='content'></div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('.content').html("<?php include('php/content.php'); ?>");
</script>
```

When the php is executed on server it replaces content with actual html inside html() function. And on client side javascript plays its role to render it.